# Listviews with same itemsource different filter

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, filter

I got 3 listviews. The itemsources is bound to an ObservableCollection the person class has an integer property(with INotifyPropertyChanged) "teamID". Now I want to filter the listviews depending on the team they are in, is there a way to do it easy(I know 2 solutions for it but I think they are not good, 1 is to make 3 ObservableCollection but that will be complex to keep track and transfer all the persons to the right ObservableCollection , or use a trigger like Visibility to Visible if the teamID is the right teamID^^)
I got 3 buttons and if I select an item(person) on any of the listviews, depending on the button clicked that person teamID will change. (But I also want him to change to the right listview depending on teamID)

Hope you understand, otherwise feel free to ask for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think It is not possible to do it without writing some code.

I would use `CollectionView` instead of binding the collection directly to the ListView. This is what WPF will do internally, but creating them by your own you will have control to many things like sort and of course filters.

Create them using `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(yourCollection)`.

Apply the filters and on the setter of your team id property do a `CollectionView.Refresh()` when team id changes. If you don't have too many data this is not a big issue. But on a lot of data `Refresh()` on three views might be a little heavy.

EDIT:

I forgot to tell you that you must set the source on each one of your ListViews to the corresponding CollectionView but I think this is obvious.

Comment: Oke will look into this later, how to use different views with 1 CollectionView and bind them to the different listviews.

Answer (score 0):

Bind to a public property

```
  public List<person> SrtedPerson1 { get { return ListView.DataSource = OriginalList.Where(x => x.TeamId==filteringTeamId).ToList(); }}
```

Have the Button call NotifyPropertyChanged("SrtedPerson1");

This alone is not going to give you dynamic update ListView.DataSource = OriginalList.Where(x => x.TeamId==filteringTeamId) as it returns iEnumerable only.

In the public I return List as if you just return iEnumerable it will get wrapped with List anyway for the control

Comment: I dunno I am not so good at this, but shoudn t I use observableCollections instead, so I don t have to call the NotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: This do works but I don t like that I have to call the NotifyPropertyChanged on the button event, it gets messy imo, I was more hoping for an answer with CollectionViewSource or something, however if there doesn t comes a better answer I ll you let your answer be the correct one. But then I ll rewrite my questions(because it is more advanced, it doesn t use buttons but drag & drop so it is hard to keep track where to use the raisepropertychange event)

Comment: If are going to have a button and a button event then NotifyPropertyChanged is just one line of code.   The output from OriginalList.Where(x => x.TeamId==filteringTeamId) is not an ObservableCollection.   You said you wanted a button the make the the change.  A ColletionViewsSource is more used for a static filter.

Comment: It is 2 lines of code, because I have to upgrade the teamold and the teamnew id. Otherwise the person will be 2 times in the list

Comment: Oh, 2 lines of code, excuse me.  Does it work?  And I don't know what upgrade means.  I suggest you post the code you have tried.